# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se expanda un mat-expansion-panel sin deshabilitarlo?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

estoy haciendo un menú para mi web en angular con material angular agregado y estoy usando los mat-accordion, hay algunos que no tienen contenido dentro así que quiero que esos que no tiene nada que mostrar no se expandan o pero que sigan funcionando como un botón mas para el menú la idea no es deshabilitarlo porque no lo podría usar como un botón intente hacer esto

```
.mat-expansion-panel{
    height: 44px;
}
.mat-expansion-panel-header{
    height: 44px;
}
```

de esta forma hago que se vean estáticos pero aun así el mat-expansion-panel-body sigue apareciendo de forma que cuando este este abierto el hover deja de funcionar